# indexing a data frame using multiple date time in Python

Tags: python, indexing

I have a data frame CaliSimNG

```
    CaliSimNG

              Date       Sim1       Sim2       Sim3      Sim4       Sim5  
    0   2018-01-01   4.410628   5.181019   3.283512  2.289767   6.930455   
    1   2018-01-02   3.919023   5.572350   4.899945  1.858528   7.724655   
    2   2018-01-03   4.804969   4.477524   7.339943  1.963685   8.186425   
    3   2018-01-04   4.226408   4.208243  18.850381  1.967792  27.341537   
    4   2018-01-05   4.441108   3.731662  14.349406  2.000143   7.804742
```

I want to select the row from certain dates. The dates are marked by date time array DesiredDates

```
    DesiredDates
    array(['2018-01-01T19:00:00.000000000-0500',
           '2018-01-04T19:00:00.000000000-0500', 
            '2018-01-05T19:00:00.000000000-0500'], 
            dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

how can I get a subset of CaliSimNG using the datetime index in DesiredDates?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do an inner join using the pandas "merge" function as described [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html).

For example:

```
left = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['date1', 'date2', 'date3'], 'v': [1, 2, 3]})
right = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['date2']})
joined = pd.merge(left, right, on='Date')
```

Produces:

```
joined
    Date  v
0  date2  2
```

Comment: Hi, what if I need to use "DesiredDates" to index the data frame? This is just a simplified example and CaliSimNG and DesiredDates can have thousands of dates.

Comment: Oh, I thought you wanted a range of dates. In that case you should probably use pandas join methods: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html

Comment: @hassISC See new answer :)